# Parentheses in variable declaration

Tags: java, casting

Sorry if this is **super** basic, I just wasn't sure how to search for this.

I'm looking over an example from an exam I just got back, and I think I had some comprehension errors here. Here's the given code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, i1 = 2, i2 = 4;
    double d, d1 = 3.0, d2 = 4.5;
}

static void foo(int x, double y) {
    double z = x + y;
    System.out.println("Value of foo is " + z);
}

static double foo(double x, double y) {
    return x - y;
}

static int foo(double x, int y) {
    int z = (int) (x + y)
    return z;
}
```

It then asks you to give the value return, output printed, or description of error (like double `d` may not have been initialized) for various method calls.

My questions are:

1. What does the operation `(int)(x+y)` do in the `(double x, int y)` part? It's obviously not multiplication. Couldn't figure that one out.
2. Some of the method calls would ask for two `int`s. Java turns them into `double`s, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is Type Casting - (Down Sizing) in your case.

Since x is a double in your example and y is an int. 
x+y returns a double.

Since int z is pointing a double value. It is downsized with a Type casting to Int.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the operation `(int)(x+y)` do in the `(double x, int y)` part? It's obviously not multiplication. Couldn't figure that one out.

Is a type casting, it means the result of the addition will be casted as `int`.

> Some of the method calls would ask for two `int`s. Java turns them into `double`s, right?

No, Java won't do that. `int` and `double` values are different.

Answer (score 1):

1. `(int)(x+y)` is a cast of the result from `double` to `int`.
2. Java won't coerce ints into doubles.  They're different representations of numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the operation (int)(x+y) do in the (double x, int y) part? It's obviously not multiplication. Couldn't figure that one out.

This is called explicit type casting. The operation `(int)(x+y)` means that `x` and `y` are added and their result is then casted to `int`. It means that even if `x` and `y` are `double`, the result `x+y` will be cast to an `int`. In the method, `static int foo(double x, int y)`, `x` is a `double` is added to `y`, which is an `int`. The result of a double added to `int`, will result in a `double`. Thus to convert it to `int`, it is casted as `(int)(x+y)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. if x = 4.5 and y =5 and you call method foo(x,y) then your method definition foo(double x, int y) is called. In java JVM will load the class matching its arguments. And Sum of x and y will yield you 9.5 which is double. And the (int) is simply type casting double value of 9.5 to its int value which is 9.
2. sum of two ints is always an int, sum of an int and double will return you a double value.

Answer (score -2):

`double` + `int` == `double`

```
return 5/2   // returns 2 (not turned into doubles)
return 5.0/2 // returns 2.5 (turned into doubles)
return (int)(5.0/2)  // returns 2 (turned into doubles, then turned into int)
return 5d/2 // returns 2.5 (turned into doubles)
```

Comment: So here's why I decided to downvote.  Your answer doesn't answer the question.  Simple as that.  You answer a *part* of it in a very convoluted way, but I'm reluctant to call that an answer at all since you briefly touch on the actual cast, and then proceed to use double literals.